# my bot delete all my message when i sent it

Tags: node.js, discord.js

```
   client.on('message', message => {
   if (message.content.indexOf(conf.prefix)){
   if (message.author.bot) return;
   message.delete({ timeout: 0 }); 
  }
});

   client.on('message', message => {
   if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes("request recieved")) 
   message.delete({ timeout: 40 });
   else return;
});
```

when i sent a message it deleted and i try to remove the manage message it don't do anything
I tried to get the condition it need to work but it just don't stop deleting my message

Comment: what are you trying to do? your intent is unclear. Your bot is definitely deleting messages.  Is that what you want or not?

Comment: 1) Why do you have 2 message events? 2) you have `message.delete({ timeout: 0 });` firing on each event, ofcourse it deletes every message you send

Comment: trying to delete the message contant prefix but it delete all

Answer (score 1):

First of all, remove one of your message events, you definitely only need one. Having multiple causes only errors.

The issue with your code is that it can't understand your prefix finding, so if you want to delete all messages with your prefix in them, do:

```js
client.on('message', message => {
   if (message.content.startsWith(conf.prefix)){
        if (message.author.bot) return;
        message.delete(); 
  }
});
```